# Check if Vimeo video loads inside iframe - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

I have a form where a user enters a video id from Vimeo and there page then previews the video in an iframe.

How do I check if the video was found?

The JS for loading the iframe is:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#video', function(event) {
        removeErrorHighlight('#video');
        if (this.value == '') {
            $('#vimeo_preview').empty();
        } else {
            if (! $('#vimeo_preview').is(':empty')) {
                $('#vimeo_preview').empty();
            }
            $('#vimeo_preview').append('<iframe id="iframeVimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + this.value + '" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    });
```

I have tried multiple ways to read the content of the iFrame but Chrome keeps blocking the "cross domain" iframe access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to tell if the video itself loads if it is from a different domain. This is due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Hi @Brendan Long, I understood this. But is there no way to search the content of the iFrame to see if I find a 404?

Comment: Nope, that because of the same origin policy. You don't have access to that content.